# Org-ref: how to get the BibTex entries in Helm sorted alphabetically? // what is "org-ref-helm-cite"?

Tags: org-ref, helm-bibtex

Sorry if my question is not clear enough, I'm really a beginner.
In 2017 someone was trying to sort alphabetically (or by date I guess also) references when using `org-ref` and `helm-bibtex` - see the [question and answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31645/org-ref-how-to-get-the-bibtex-entries-in-helm-sorted-alphabetically).
I'm also looking for this functionality.

John Kitchin answered that we should use `org-ref-helm-cite` backend.
When I'm trying `M-x org-ref-helm-cite`, I don't find `org-ref-helm-cite`.

How can I sort bibtex entries alphabetically (or by year) in Helm? Either through `org-ref-helm-cite` or through some other method?

Comment: Can you add a link to that old question? And please add it to your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Are you looking for `org-ref-helm-cite'? Or are you looking for how to sort BibTex entries alphabetically with Helm? The question isn't clear. Please pose only one question per post.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

1) The old question : Org-ref: how to get the BibTex entries in Helm sorted alphabetically? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31645/org-ref-how-to-get-the-bibtex-entries-in-helm-sorted-alphabetically
2) I'm just looking for how to sort bibtex entries alphabetically or by year with Helm. Any solution would be good for me. Thanks

Comment: Please add all relevant details *to the question*, which needs to stand on its own. Adding a comment does not fulfill that purpose (and comments can be deleted).

Comment: I edited your question to add the relevant info.

Comment: I don't think you can. Normally you would type `2022` to get a list of recent publications.

Answer (score 0):

This was a feature in the old version 2, you could use M- for that. It is not currently implemented in org-ref version 3.

The code that did that can be found at https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/org-ref-2/org-ref-helm-cite.el#L148. I don't use helm these days, so I don't know how easy it would be to add it back to version 3.

Comment: Dear John, Thanks for you answer. I'm going to see what I can do with that.